# Google Sheets Script parseCsv - How to avoid converting text to numbers, data and formulas

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the following code to import a csv file:

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvFile);
```

It is working but with some specific numbers, like "2.02" it is converting the text to date.

If I use the File > Import Menu, I'm able to avoid this automatic conversion, but I was not able to set this condition as a parameter on this function above (parseCSV).

Is it possible to use parseCSV and avoid this automatic text to date conversion?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a sample CSV data for replicating `with some specific numbers, like "2.02" it is converting the text to date.`?

Comment: I tested the exact number and it is being returned as a number not a date, as @Tanaike has suggested please provide a full CSV that is giving you the error so we can try to reproduce it. Also take into account that the input of `parseCsv` is the string, not the file, or blob itself.

Comment: I cannot forward this file nor I was able to create a test file that has a similar error. I will keep trying to create an example but the point here is to find a way to avoid the automatic textToDate feature on the parseCsv function. There must be a way to do it otherwise the File > Import menu would not offer such a possibility. Thank you!

Comment: I'm telling you, for me the number is not being converted to a date. Could you explain how is your data laid out? Just copy some lines (deleting all the personal information) that you have problems with, so it can be tested with the `parseCsv` function, but for the value `2.02` it just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can hint the sheet to parse "2.02" as string by prefixing the values with an apostrophe. In other words, change "2.02" to "'2.02".